# Make function template of span<auto> accept collections with inferrence of element type at call sites

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, parameter-passing, std-span

I'd like to be able to pass values of as wide as possible a range of types to functions based on a template accepting `span`. I've got the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <span>
using namespace std;

void f(span<auto> s) {
    for(auto &a : s)
        cout << a << endl;
}

template<class T>
void h(T &&x) {
    f<remove_reference_t<decltype(x[0])>>(forward<T>(x));
}

int main() {
    int a[]{5, 6};
    auto b = array{7, 9, 3, 1};
    h(a);
    h(b);
}
```

It works, but I expected to be able to do it without the helper function `h`, just with argument initialization, thus: `f({a})`, `f({b})`. Is there a way to achieve it or something similar?

Comment: I think `f(span{a})` is simple enough.

Comment: I assume you cannot change the signature of f? https://godbolt.org/z/fjbabMojj

Comment: @康桓瑋 for that to work you would need to make `f` more general: https://godbolt.org/z/89Kvx6cdW. In the definition of f, it only accepts spans where the second template argument matches the default parameter, that is `std::dynamic_extent`, But `span{a}` as an extent of 2.

Comment: @joergbrech, I can! Thanks for pointing me in this direction. I've made your code both simpler and more general thus: https://godbolt.org/z/bc1oPx8nb. The span is defined once and kept in the variable `s` for possible reuse in hypothetical further statements of `f`. But I still wonder if an extra variable is necessary, or maybe there's a way to do it alongside argument passing.